Where I can find "set active" node in the blueprint to activate Niagara system component?
In the main level editor I placed Niagara system component called shell and I need to activate it from the blueprint so I opened level blueprint and searched for set active shell but I can not find set active at all whether I select context sensitive or not. Where I can find this node?
Unreal 5.4.4

While Niagara selected when I right click I found only option to get reference to parent cube but not for Niagara


You need to get a reference to the Niagara system component in the level then you can call the activate function from the object returned by get shell from the Niagra component reference.
Edit:
I thought that you already had the object reference to the ChamferCube4 object in the level and from that Get a reference to its StaticMeshComponent0. From that node, the Get of the Niagra component will be visible.

See updated question please
